# best storage place for a temporary string?

Tags: cassandra, storage, rdbms, database, nosql

Our application generates a short-lived string, about a dozen chars, that is supposed to be consumed by our clients later for only once. After the consumption it is gone. Or it becomes invalid in 10 minutes without consumption. The storage of this string needs to be global as the requests consuming the string is stateless.

We have been using global cache before for storing this string. It works perfectly function-wise. However, it does not fit semantically. There have been incidents before when the cache server is down, our application cannot function correctly. We are searching for alternatives to global cache for storing this short temporary string. it needs to be

```
global
fast write
fast read
fast delete
supports timeout
```

update is never a concern. NoSQL sounds a better place than RDBMS but I am not totally sure. Any recommendations/suggestions/hints are deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For Cassandra:

high availability - yes

global - yes

fast write - yes

fast read - yes

fast delete - yes, but beware of creating tombstones.  If you are looking for a global queue, then that is an anti-pattern in Cassandra.  If you just want each client to get the latest string (i.e. overwrite the last value on insert), then you'd be okay.

supports timeout - yes if you are talking about the data.  Cassandra can set a TTL (Time To Live) when data is inserted.  But again, beware of creating tombstones.

Comment: Hi, Jim, thank you for the reply. There is no queue, it is just like a map, if a new string is created for the same client-user pair, the previous one should be overwritten. In terms of read/write, do you think cassandra's performance is comparable or better than MySQL? Just want to be sure

Comment: actually If multiple strings are created for the same client-user pair, depending on which one is consumed, others just naturally timeout.

Comment: I would guess Cassandra performs as well or better than MySQL, but it all depends on how things are set up, the hardware used, etc.  When you say a string is "consumed", that implies a queue.  If it's not a queue you would just say "read" since you read the value of a certain key without deleting that value.

Comment: Oh, I am not sure about Cassandra terminology. If a read followed by a delete means a queue, then there is a queue there

Comment: Well if you're looking for a global queue, you might want to look into something like apache kafka.

Comment: Please don't mind me, I am a little confused. I only need a storage for a short string with availability, fast create/read/delete, why am I looking at a distributed queue now?